# Draw SVG from json data using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, svg

[image: Should Output]

How to draw context diagram in SVG base on the returned json data?

Sample json data:

```
 "data":{
         "PageType":"Home",
         "CatId":0,
         "Category":"",
         "ObjectId":0,
         "Object":"",
         "Total":1,
         "Prev":[
            {
               "type":"Prev1",
               "Count":1,
               "Time":0
            },
             {
               "type":"Prev2",
               "Count":2,
               "Time":0
            },
             {
               "type":"Prev3",
               "Count":3,
               "Time":0
            },
         ],
         "Next":[
            {
               "type":"Next1",
               "Count":1,
               "Time":1000
            }
              {
               "type":"Next2",
               "Count":2,
               "Time":1000
            },
              {
               "type":"Next3",
               "Count":3,
               "Time":1000
            }
         ]
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is not a problem, it is just implementation exercise. I'm not giving you the result, but just some pointers. These are the basic elements of your SVG. The `<g>` is grouping the elements and can be moved around with the transform attribute.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    line, rect {stroke-width: 1; stroke: navy; fill: none;}
    text {fill: navy;}
  </style>
  <g transform="translate(200 150)">
    <rect x="-50" y="-20" width="100" height="40" rx="10" />
    <text dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" width="100">Text 1</text>
    <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="100" y2="60" /> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

Then it needs to be dynamic. You know the size of each element and the spacing. With a `forEach()` loop you can loop through all the elements in a list and "spread" them out. I just "append" the new SVG elements with `...innerHTML += ...`

```js
var prev = {
  "Prev": [{
      "type": "Prev1",
      "Count": 1,
      "Time": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "Prev2",
      "Count": 2,
      "Time": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "Prev3",
      "Count": 3,
      "Time": 0
    },
  ]
};

var drawing = document.getElementById('drawing');

prev.Prev.forEach((p, i, arr) => {
  let x = 55;
  let y = 250/arr.length*i+50;
  drawing.innerHTML += `<g transform="translate(${x} ${y})">
        <rect x="-50" y="-20" width="100" height="40" rx="10" />
        <text dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" width="100">${p.type}</text>
        <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="100" y2="${250/arr.length-y+50}" /> 
      </g>`;
});
```

```html
<svg id="drawing" viewBox="0 0 400 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    line, rect {stroke-width: 1; stroke: navy; fill: none;}
    text {fill: navy;}
  </style>
</svg>
```

This should be fine for implementing the entire thing yourself :-)

Comment: @chrwal mind explaining this ? let y = 250/arr.length*i+50; btw this is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @mojoe the height of the SVG image is 300. 250 is just an arbitrary number less than 300. arr is the array that is iterated over (aka prev.Prev). It has 3 items (arr.length = 3). 50 is the starting point, so the y position of the first item will be: 250/3*0+50=50, second: 250/3*1+5=133.33 etc. To move the y2 for the line is kind of the same, first: 250/3-50+50=83.33. You can adjust the no 250 and 50 so it fits you requirements.