# Formula for <rect>dynamic spacing in svg

Tags: javascript, svg, formula

How to make dynamic spacing base on the no. of returned data? I want that if only one data is returned, it is positioned in middle. If two data returned it will adjust, and so on.

```js
   var prev = {
      "Prev": [{
          "type": "Prev1",
        },
        {
          "type": "Prev2",
        },
        {
          "type": "Prev3",
        },
       
      ]
    };
    
    var draw = document.getElementById('drawing');
    
    prev.Prev.forEach((p, i, arr) => {
      let x = 55;
      let y = 250/arr.length*i+50;
      draw.innerHTML += `<g transform="translate(${x} ${y})">
            <rect x="-50" y="-20" width="100" height="40" rx="10" />
            <text dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" width="100">${p.type}</text>
            <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="100" y2="${250/arr.length-y+50}" /> 
            </g>`;
    });
    
        draw.innerHTML += `<g>
            <rect x="150" y="110" width="100" height="40" rx="10" />
            <text  x="200" y="130" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" width="100">BASE</text>
            </g>`;
```

```css
        line, rect {stroke-width: 1; stroke: navy; fill: none;}
        text {fill: navy;}
```

```html
 <svg id="drawing" viewBox="0 0 400 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">


    </svg>
```

Comment: `y2="${y}"` not working?

Comment: @dalelandry not working. If only one data returned, it positioned on top left, not on middle.

Comment: you may take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781957/draw-svg-from-json-data-using-javascript/68782806#68782806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple.  You just have to calculate the top of the first rect and then add on `i` times the distance from the top of one item to the top of the next.

```js
var prev = {
  "Prev": [{
      "type": "Prev1",
    },
    {
      "type": "Prev2",
    },
    {
      "type": "Prev3",
    }
   
  ]
};

var draw = document.getElementById('drawing');
var RECT_HEIGHT = 40;
var RECT_SPACING = 50;
var SVG_HEIGHT = 300;

prev.Prev.forEach((p, i, arr) => {
  // number of rects/graph items
  let num = arr.length;
  // total height of all <num> 
  let totalHeight = num * RECT_HEIGHT + (num - 1) * RECT_SPACING;
  let x = 55;
  // final position = position of first rect + i * distance_between_rects
  let y = (SVG_HEIGHT - totalHeight) / 2   // top of first rect
          + i * (RECT_HEIGHT + RECT_SPACING);  // i * distance_between_rects

  draw.innerHTML += `<g transform="translate(${x} ${y})">
        <rect x="-50" y="0" width="100" height="40" rx="10" />
        <text y="20" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle"
              width="100">${p.type}</text>
        <line x1="50" y1="20" x2="100" y2="${SVG_HEIGHT / 2 - y}" /> 
        </g>`;
});

/*
    draw.innerHTML += `<g>
        <rect x="150" y="110" width="100" height="40" rx="10" />
        <text  x="200" y="130" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" width="100">BASE</text>
        </g>`;
*/
```

```css
svg {
  background: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg id="drawing" viewBox="0 0 400 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    line, rect {stroke-width: 1; stroke: navy; fill: none;}
    text {fill: navy;}
  </style>
</svg>
```

Comment: this is an additional question. How do i put text on the middle of the lines dynamically?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "dynamically"?  Do you mean after the SVG has been created?

Comment: yes like I will display the text also in the center of the each lines. Can be either way, after the svg created or during svg creates, as long as text shows. I find a bit hard making the right formula.

Comment: For centering horizontally, `text-anchor="middle"` is the correct approach.  For vertically centering `alignment-baseline="middle"` works. However it can look funny depending on your text. For example, it can look wrong if your next contains no descenders, like here.  An alternative is to nudge the text down a little using `dy` with an `em` value. Eg. `dy="0.35em"`. You might find you prefer that approach.

Comment: To change the text after creating it, start by selecting your `<text>` element somehow. Eg. by id: `var elem = getElementById("myTextId")`.  Then you can change the text displayed using `elem.textContent = "New text content";`.

Comment: https://ibb.co/hmndGPp something like in the image. Text just normally displayed in the middle of each lines.